# What is the demand function p(x)?

Tags: calculus, optimization

The marginal revenue of a certain commodity is $R^1(x)=-3x^2+4x+32$
where $x$ is the level of production in thousands. Assume $R(0)=0$ Find $R(x)$. What is the demand function of $p(x)$?

I took the integral and got $R(x)=-x^3+2x^2+32x$

I'm not sure how to find the demand function though.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The first term in your integral should be $x^3$

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake when copying the answer to here.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The revenue function is $R(x)=p(x)\cdot x$ Thus you can calculate $p(x)$.

Comment: So, do I just factor out the x to get p(x). It ends up being p(x)=-x^2+2x+32 or am I off?

Comment: Yes. Note that the condition $R(0)=0$ is satisfied, because $R(0)=-0^3+2\cdot 0^2+32\cdot 0=0$.